# matplotlib.pyplot: add horizontal line to sub-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

This code (matplotlib.pyplot) gives me the plot in the link below:

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(px,py)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(curve)
```

[2 plots example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3jE9.png)
--> I want to add a horizontal line in the second sub-plot at 100.000. How can I do that? The colors of both plots shall stay the same/synchronized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline` of matplotlib which adds a horizontal line across the axis. If you need to set any further parameters, refer to the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
plt.axhline(100000, color="gray")
```